# Scala - Combining two sequences to consecutively increasing triples

Tags: scala

What is a nice and efficient functional way of solving the following problem? In imperative style, this can be done in linear time.

Given two *sorted* sequences `p` and `q`, `f` returns a sequence `r` (or any collection) of triples where for every triple `(a,b,c)` in `r`, the following hold:

1. (`a` < `b` < `c`)
2. One of the following two holds:

   - `a`,`c` are two *consecutive* elements `p`, and `b` is in `q`
   - `a`,`c` are two *consecutive* elements `q`, and `b` is in `p`

***Example:*** Consider the following two sequences.

```
val p = Seq(1,4,5,7,8,9)
val q = Seq(2,3,6,7,8,10)
```

Then `f(p,s)` computes the following sequence:

```
Seq((1,2,4), (1,3,4), (5,6,7), (3,4,6), (3,5,6), (8,9,10))
```

**Current solution:** I do not find this one very elegant. I am looking for a better one.

```
    def consecutiveTriplesOneWay(s1: Seq[Int], s2:Seq[Int]) = {
        for {
            i <- 0 until s1.size - 1 if s1(i) < s1(i+1)
            j <- 0 until s2.size if s1(i) < s2(j) &&  s2(j) < s1(i+1)
        } yield (s1(i), s2(j), s1(i+1))
    }

    def consecutiveTriples(s1: Seq[Int], s2:Seq[Int]) =
        consecutiveTriplesOneWay(s1, s2) ++ consecutiveTriplesOneWay(s2, s1)

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val p = Seq(1,4,5,7,8,9)
        val q = Seq(2,3,6,7,8,10)

        consecutiveTriples(p, q).foreach(println(_))
    }
```

***Edit:*** My imperative solution

```
def consecutiveTriplesOneWayImperative(s1: Seq[Int], s2:Seq[Int]) = {
    var i = 0
    var j = 0
    val triples = mutable.MutableList.empty[(Int,Int,Int)]
    while (i < s1.size - 1 && j < s2.size) {
        if (s1(i) < s2(j) && s2(j) < s1(i + 1)) {
            triples += ((s1(i), s2(j), s1(i + 1)))
            j += 1
        } else if (s1(i) >= s2(j))
            j += 1
        else
            i += 1
    }
    triples.toSeq
}

def consecutiveTriples(s1: Seq[Int], s2:Seq[Int]) = 
    consecutiveTriplesOneWayImperative(s1,s2) ++ 
            consecutiveTriplesOneWayImperative(s2,s1)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What about functional style makes translating the imperative solution hard? Have you used the typical while -> fold/recurse approach?

Comment: Do you have some code? Because it sounds like an exercise, which we should solve instead of you.

Comment: This looks like homework.  If this was ever written in an imperative style, the user should have noticed (3, 5, 6) missing as a valid answer.

Comment: @Karl: Thanks for spotting the typo.

:D Not a homework. Long time out of college.

Comment: I added my current solution that I do not like very much. There has to be a more elegant way of doing this

Comment: Is `(7,8,9)` really supposed to be in the output?  7 and 9 are not consecutive elements of either p or q.

Comment: Your current one looks like O(n^2)

Comment: Yes, I know. I am trying to get it done better.

Comment: Post the iterative solution (in whichever language)

Comment: I edited the question and added imperative solution

Answer (score 1):

Imperative solution translated to tailrec. Bit verbose but works

```
def consecutiveTriplesRec(s1: Seq[Int], s2: Seq[Int]) = {
  @tailrec
  def consTriplesOneWay(left: Seq[Int], right: Seq[Int],
                        triples: Seq[(Int, Int, Int)]): Seq[(Int, Int, Int)] = {
    (left, right) match {
      case (l1 :: l2 :: ls, r :: rs) =>
        if (l1 < r && r < l2) consTriplesOneWay(left, rs, (l1, r, l2) +: triples)
        else if (l1 >= r) consTriplesOneWay(left, rs, triples)
        else consTriplesOneWay(l2 :: ls, right, triples)
      case _ => triples
    }
  }
  consTriplesOneWay(s1, s2, Nil) ++ consTriplesOneWay(s2, s1, Nil)
}
```